# $ sign in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function

I've found some weird for me function in the project that I'm currently working on:

```
Building.Widget.ClientIdV2 = function Building$Widget$ClientIdV2() {
...
```

What does $ mean here and what does the "name" of this function mean (Building$Widget$ClientIdV2) ? I've seen also `... = function () {` code so far..

Thank you.

Comment: The `$` can be used as part of any JavaScript variable or function or property name. It doesn't mean anything more than `B` or `z` mean.

Comment: It is not a reserved character if you are not putting it in front.

Comment: @TonyWu: It's not a reserved character if you *are* putting it in front, either. JavaScript variable names can start with `$` (hence jQuery and PrototypeJS using it on its own, just `$` or in PrototypeJS's case `$`, `$$`, and a few others).

Comment: @Dedyshka Do you also want an explanation for `... = function () {`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Really? So I can use it if I am not putting a bracket after it? Thank you for telling me about that : )

Comment: AngularJS use `$` at start of built-in variables too. Like `$scope`, `$q`, `$timeout` etc... And `$$` for some properties it adds to objects.

Comment: @TonyWu: Sure, `var $foo = ...` and such are perfectly fine. If you use `$` on its own, just ensure that either A) You're not using a library, like jQuery, that already uses `$`, or B) You're using jQuery's `noConflict` (or a similar feature in whatever lib you're using).

Comment: Thanks all, for the most part I understood the snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dollar sign has no special significance. It is just a character you can use in an identifier.

The name of the function can be used to refer to the function from inside its own scope (which can be useful for recursive functions) and will appear in useful places like stack traces.

Comment: can I use the object's name (that is on the left side - Building.Widget.ClientIdV2) inside the function itself or it won't be accessible ?

Comment: Like any variable, it will be in scope so long as it isn't masked by a variable of the same name inside the function. Like any variable, it can be overwritten by other code. It is however, just a variable whose value is the function. It is not the function name (which is a feature internal to the function).

Answer (score 1):

`$` is just another character you can use in an identifier, it has no intrinsic special meaning. It could be `Q` or `_` just as easily.

In that particular example, the original author is naming the function in a way that they can readily see that it's the `ClientIdV2` function on the `Widget` object on the `Building` object. But that's just the author's convention. That's useful for looking at call stacks and such.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's someones naming convention. You can preety much put anything that you want in Javascript variable names. You should try finding general naming conventions in Javascript in case that you're interested in that(it will make your work with other developers much easier).

For example, some people like to put the $ before jQuery variables, implying that they can chain functions on that selection.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript it's completely valid to use $ in names, just like letters or underscores, so syntactically it means nothing special. Thought it's frequently used to give extra semantic meaning to names, for eg. it may indicate that a variable is special to a system (internal variable, global, etc.). In your case I believe $ indicates object hierarchy. The use of $ is just conventional.